# Keychain kSecValueData with weird not-showing characters at last

Tags: objective-c, ios, passwords, character, keychain

I've been searching a solution for this problem, but it seems I'm the only one on the Internet who has encountered a problem like this.

I'm using the keychain wrapper class provided by Apple to store the user and password as it should be stored. When I want to get the user value back, is as easy as doing:

```
NSString *user = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

Retriveing the password should be as straightforward as the username:

```
NSString *pass = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

But after that, trying to print them with an NSLog, nothing is shown on console AFTER the pass. For example:

```
NSLog(@"user: <%@>, pass: <%@>, something after the pass", user, pass);
```

The output of this NSLog is:

```
user: <123456>, pass: <5433
```

Invoking [pass length] gives me always a number greater than the actual length of the pass (in this example, 10, when I would say its length is actually 4).

I have no idea of what's going on. I made a workaround to patch this problem while I try to find a proper solution (looking every character's integer value and allowing only the ones which are numbers, letters and some symbols).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to store a CFDataRef object as an NSString object, and then print it is a string using %@. It is a data object, not a string. If you'd like to see it as a string, you must first convert it into a string. Try something like the code below to convert it into a string before you try to log it:

```
NSData *passData = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[passData bytes] length:[passData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

kSecValueData is of type: typedef const void * CFTypeRef;

You shouldn't typecast it to a NSString.
Try directly posting it into the NSLog like this.

```
NSLog(@"user <%@> pass <%@>", [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount], [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But I'm sorry to say it doesn't work. Nothing appears after the password, just like before :(